# Dicom US with multiple values

Tags: c#, parsing, binary, short, dicom

I'm currently trying to parse some files with my DICOM parser, and I've come across a problem with multiple US (usigned short) values in a Data element

```
(0018,1310) Aquisition Matrix:

0x55 0x53  {tag}
0x08 0x00  {lenght}
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x00 {value}
```

Only, as far as I can find in the specification, a datalementen with a US VR can only contains 2 bytes (after all its a short). I'm not quite sure how I shall implement this then. Does anyone know where this is specified or how I should solve this?

Comment: good you found it, but you should make an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out what it is. I forgot about Value Multiplicities of elements. In the dicom dictionary you can find these values. (0018,1310) Aquisition Matrix has a VM of 4. So there it is.